# Trying to sort out Json with Nested Lists in Android

Tags: java, android, json, nested-lists

I Have Json I am receiving and parsing Ok, but am a bit lost in how to deal with it now.

```
"success": true,
"data": {
"endingIndex": 1,
"segmentCount": 2,
"startingIndex": 0,
"totalCount": 2,
"comments": [
  {
    "childCount": 1,
    "content": "This is a root Comment",
    "id": 2342246,
    "parentID": null,
    "submissionID": 623234,
    "children": {
      "endingIndex": 0,
      "segmentCount": 1,
      "startingIndex": 0,
      "totalCount": 1,
      "comments": [
        {
          "childCount": 1,
          "content": "This is second Level Comment",
          "id": 2342275,
          "parentID": 2342246,
          "submissionID": 623234,
          "children": {
            "endingIndex": 0,
            "segmentCount": 1,
            "startingIndex": 0,
            "totalCount": 1,
            "comments": [
              {
                "childCount": 0,
                "content": "This is a third Level Comment",
                "id": 2342310,
                "parentID": 2342246,
                "submissionID": 623234,
                "children": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "childCount": 0,
    "content": "This is first Level Comment too!",
    "id": 2342298,
    "parentID": null,
    "submissionID": 623234,
    "children": null
  }
]
```

I have modelled two Objects:

```
public class Segment{ 

private List<Comment> comments;
private int endingIndex;
private int segmentCount;
private int startingIndex;
private int totalCount;

//getters...
    }
```

and

```
public class Comment{

private int childCount;
private String content;
private int id;
private int parentID;
private Segment children;

//getters...
}
```

The issue I am having is trying to deal with the data. I want to make a list of staggered comments, but my brain is a bit burnt out thinking of lists of lists.

I receive the root Segment from my Api request

```
CommentSegment fetchedCommentList = new CommentSegment(api);
//this should contain all the info
```

Then I'm thinking I need a list of the comments inside

```
List<Comment> rootComments = new ArrayList<>;
for(Comment comment : fetchedCommentList.getComments()){
    rootComments.add(new Comment(comment));
}
///This should get me the first level, but how to I get the additional 
// levels and get it ordered correctly?
```

Now my brain is exploding, Where do I go from here?

Comment: > Now my brain is exploding, Where do I go from here? - The ER, I guess?

Comment: Recursion might be the simplest solution.

Comment: @gregschlom I did and they said, " we can't help you, try Stack Overflow."

Comment: @user234461 right, I am thinking for i loop, but how do i go to the next level and run it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a queue and then just go down the tree of data like this:

```
private List<Comment> treeQueue(Segment parent) {
    List<Comment> comments = new List<Comment>();
    Queue queue = new LinkedList();


    for (Comment comment : parent.getcomments()) {

        queue.add(comment);

        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Comment node = (Comment)queue.remove();
            comments.add(comment);
            if (node.childCount > 0) {
                for (Comment child : ((Segment)node.getchildren()).getcomments()) {
                    queue.add(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return comments;
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'm giving it a try

Comment: I got it working thank you so much. Now i just need to make them appear staggered in the Ui.